# Line bundle $L$ on the complex torus $T$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

For a line bundle $L$ on the complex torus $T$, the pullback $p^{*}L$ by the canonical holomorphic mapping $p:\mathbb{C}^{g}\rightarrow T$ is a line bundle over $\mathbb{C}^{g}$.

I wonder why this is true. Furthermore, I would like a reference to read about line bundle.

thank you.

Comment: The pullback of a rank $k$ vector bundle is always a rank $k$ vector bundle.

Comment: You could show me a reference about line bundle?

Comment: One hint towards the fact mentioned in the above comment is to compute the stalks of the pullback (using https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0098).

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a pullback of a bundle $E$ over $B$ induced by morphism of manifolds $f:B′→B$ is defined as $ \{(b′,e):f(b′)=π(e)\}$

[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_bundle)

Basically that means that every $\pi'^{-1}(x')$ is the same as  $\pi^{-1}(f(x'))$

$\pi^{-1}(f(x'))$ is a one-dimensional vector space.

You can try reading about all vector bundles in homotopic algebra and Geometry style.

Norman Steenrod, The Topology of Fibre Bundles ;
Dale Husemoller, Fibre Bundles (looked at it and liked it more)

Note that line bundles are associated with algebraic divisors, and
[Picard Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_group) tensor product is actually the divisor summation.

If you want to read about bundles from algebaic geometry point of view, try looking at Hartshorne's Algebraic geometry, but be prepared that you will see "locally free sheaves" instead of "locally trivial vector bundles".

If you want to look at torus line bundle classifications, open the beginning of
Mumford, Abelian Varieties.